# Maven doesn't locate dependecies in secondary mirrors

Tags: maven

I have a maven project with dependencies to the central repository and several to a local artifactory repository. When I try to run `mvn rpm:rpm` the dependencies related to the central repository are resolved, but those related to the local repository aren't.

My configuration looks like (schematically):

```
<mirrors>
    <mirror>central</mirror>
</mirrors>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <repository>local-repo1</repository>
        <repository>local-repo2</repository>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: Better use a repository manager and configure other repositories in the repository manager.

Comment: so.. have you tried having them outside profile conf, do they work then? do they work if you use other maven commands, is rpm the only one problematic? Please clarify what you've tried and what happened.

Comment: I have tried to use 3 diffrent mirrors each point to another repository, every mirror by it self worked, but when i used them all together it use only one of the mirrors and didnt find packeges from the two other repositories.